# Add column with number of duplicated values within groups and number of unique values within groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
Groups Names
G1     A
G1     A
G1     B
G1     B
G1     C
G1     C
G1     C
G1     D
G2     A
G2     B
G2     C
G3     A
G3     A
G4     F
G4     F
G4     E
```

And I would like to count for each `Groups` the number of duplicated (at least 2 times) of values within the column `Names` and add this information on a new column called `Nb_duplicated`. And I would like also to add another column called `Number_unique_names` which will be the number of unique `Names` values within each `Groups`.

I should then get:

```
Groups Names Nb_duplicated Number_unique_names
G1     A     3             4
G1     A     3             4
G1     B     3             4
G1     B     3             4
G1     C     3             4
G1     C     3             4
G1     C     3             4
G1     D     3             4
G2     A     0             3
G2     B     0             3
G2     C     0             3
G3     A     1             1
G3     A     1             1
G4     F     1             2
G4     F     1             2
G4     E     1             2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use compute the number of unique and the number of non-duplicated names (with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)), then subtract the two to get the number of duplicated:

```
# set up group
g = df.groupby('Groups')
# get unique values
df['unique'] = g['Names'].transform('nunique')
# get non-duplicates
non_dup = g['Names'].transform(lambda x: (~x.duplicated(False)).sum())
# duplicates = unique - non-duplicates
df['duplicated'] = df['unique'] - non_dup
```

*NB. I used an intermediate variable "non_dup" here for clarity but you can use a one-liner*

output (with intermediate non_dup for clarity):

```
   Groups Names  unique  duplicated           non_dup
0      G1     A       4           3                 1
1      G1     A       4           3                 1
2      G1     B       4           3                 1
3      G1     B       4           3                 1
4      G1     C       4           3                 1
5      G1     C       4           3                 1
6      G1     C       4           3                 1
7      G1     D       4           3                 1
8      G2     A       3           0                 3
9      G2     B       3           0                 3
10     G2     C       3           0                 3
11     G3     A       1           1                 0
12     G3     A       1           1                 0
13     G4     F       2           1                 1
14     G4     F       2           1                 1
15     G4     E       2           1                 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Get duplicated values to mask by chain [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://%5Bandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with inverted mask and `keep=False` for remove unique rows and then use `sum` for count `True`s in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
m = ~df.duplicated(['Groups','Names'])
m1 = df.duplicated(['Groups','Names'], keep=False)
df['Nb_duplicated'] = (m & m1).groupby(df['Groups']).transform('sum')
df['Number_unique_names'] = m.groupby(df['Groups']).transform('sum')
print (df)
   Groups Names  Nb_duplicated  Number_unique_names
0      G1     A              3                    4
1      G1     A              3                    4
2      G1     B              3                    4
3      G1     B              3                    4
4      G1     C              3                    4
5      G1     C              3                    4
6      G1     C              3                    4
7      G1     D              3                    4
8      G2     A              0                    3
9      G2     B              0                    3
10     G2     C              0                    3
11     G3     A              1                    1
12     G3     A              1                    1
13     G4     F              1                    2
14     G4     F              1                    2
15     G4     E              1                    2
```

Performance is better in sample data, please test also in real data:

```
np.random.seed(2022)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Groups':np.random.randint(1000, size=10000),
                   'Names':np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), size=10000)})


In [104]: %%timeit
     ...: m = ~df.duplicated(['Groups','Names'])
     ...: m1 = df.duplicated(['Groups','Names'], keep=False)
     ...: df['Nb_duplicated'] = (m & m1).groupby(df['Groups']).transform('sum')
     ...: df['Number_unique_names'] = m.groupby(df['Groups']).transform('sum')
     ...: 
6.29 ms ± 50.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [105]: %%timeit
     ...: # set up group
     ...: g = df.groupby('Groups')
     ...: # get unique values
     ...: df['unique'] = g['Names'].transform('nunique')
     ...: # get non-duplicates
     ...: non_dup = g['Names'].transform(lambda x: (~x.duplicated(False)).sum())
     ...: # duplicates = unique - non-duplicates
     ...: df['duplicated'] = df['unique'] - non_dup
     ...: 
344 ms ± 8.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @chippycentra - added timings to answer, my solution is 50 times faster like accepted. There are bottleneck `nunique` and custom function in `transfrom`, so it is expected.